How to show that SU$(2) \rightarrow$ SO$(3)$ is a homomorphism.
I know there are already many questions on this site concerning the homomorphism in the title but I need to approach the problem from a different angle.
I started with the quotient map $S^3 \rightarrow S^3/C_2$ into the orbit space ($C_2$ acts on $S^3$ by switching antipodal points). This quotient map is obviously a two-fold cover. Now we have homeomorphisms: $S^3/C_2 \cong \mathbb{RP^3} \cong \text{SO}(3)$ and SU$(2) \cong S^3$. If we take $\mathbb{RP^3}$ to be $D^3$ with antipodal points on its boundary identified then we get explicitly $S^3/C_2 \rightarrow \mathbb{RP}^3, (a,b,c,d) \mapsto (a,b,c)$ and $\mathbb{RP}^3 \rightarrow \text{SO}(3)$ by associating to each vector in $v \in D^3$ the rotation about the axis $v/\|v\|$ by $\|v\| \pi$ (according f.e. To the right hand rule). Now SU$(2) \cong S^3$ follows directly from the representations
\begin{align}
    \text{SU}(2)=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}a &-\overline{b}\\  b &\overline{a}\end{pmatrix}: a, b\in\mathbb{C}, |a|^2+|b|^2=1\right\}.
\end{align}
and (by identifying $\mathbb{C}^2 \cong \mathbb{R}^4 \supset S^3$ )
\begin{align}
    S^3=\{(a,b)\in\mathbb{C}^2: |a|^2+|b|^2=1\}
\end{align}
And then defining the map:
\begin{align}
    F: S^3&\to \text{SU}(2), \quad (a,b) \mapsto \begin{pmatrix}a &-\overline{b}\\  b &\overline{a}\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
I now want to compose the cover $S^3 \rightarrow S^3/C_2$ with the homeomorphisms above to get a cover SU$(2) \rightarrow \text{SO}(3)$. Then I want to prove that this cover is also a homomorphism. Will this work, or will I need different homeomorphisms? If someone sees a nicer strategy that starts at $S^3 \rightarrow S^3/C_2$ and establishes the algebraic properties of the induced map SU$(2) \rightarrow \text{SO}(3)$ I‘d be very appreciative too.

Why do you want to do things this way? There are other ways to define the double cover which make it much more obviously a homomorphism.
